# python steady distance between signs

Tags: python, loops, time, operating-system, format

In my code, when the number increases by an additional digit at the end, the characters that make up the mock box move. When it goes from 9 to 10, from 99 to 100, it wants that vertical bar not to move. At the moment, between {x} and | spaces are inserted. My code is:

```
import time
import os
x = 0
y = 0
while True:
    print(f"""
    | -------------------------------------------------------|
    | great quote about life                                 |
    | that  can change every 0.5 sec                         |
    | {x}                                                      |
    | {y}                                                      |
    |                                                        |
    | -------------------------------------------------------|
    """)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    x += 9
    y += 9
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the length of the padding after the number. I found that in your example there should be 55 characters of space total including the number you display.

I created a helper function that calculates the length of the number using `str` and `len` in combination and calculates the padding by decrementing the amount of space the number takes up.

```py
import time
import os


def get_padding(length_of_window, i):
    return (length_of_window - len(str(i))) * ' '


def main():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    length_of_window = 55

    while True:
        print(f"""
            | -------------------------------------------------------|
            | great quote about life                                 |
            | that  can change every 0.5 sec                         |
            | {x}{get_padding(length_of_window, x)}|
            | {y}{get_padding(length_of_window, y)}|
            |                                                        |
            | -------------------------------------------------------|
            """)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        x += 9
        y += 9
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You could also use [String Format Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) directly without needing concatenation or a helper function.

```py
import time
import os


def main():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    length_of_window = 55

    while True:
        print(f"""
            | -------------------------------------------------------|
            | great quote about life                                 |
            | that  can change every 0.5 sec                         |
            | {x:<{length_of_window}}|
            | {y:<{length_of_window}}|
            |                                                        |
            | -------------------------------------------------------|
            """)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        x += 9
        y += 9
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have one more question. When i open my program in terminal i feel like i have very low Frames per second becouse the window when refresh feel like lose half of frames

Comment: I don't have that issue on my end so I can't say for sure. However, you could always increase the sleep time between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

For printing numbers with fixed spaces you can use the method .format

```
print(f"""
| -------------------------------------------------------|
| great quote about life                                 |
| that  can change every 0.5 sec                         |
"""
+
"| {:<55d}|\n    | {:<55d}|".format(x,y)
+
"""
|                                                        |
| -------------------------------------------------------|
""")
```

For more formatting options see [here](https://pyformat.info/)